# Find difference between objects keys

Tags: javascript, difference

Assuming that I have two objects with similar structure. How can I find all the keys from first object that are not included in the second and vise versa?

For example I have two objects:

```
const foo = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'baz',
    qux: 'qux'
  }
};

const bar = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'baz',
    quux: 'quux'
  },
  corge: 'corge'
};
```

The props that are different are:`foo.bar.qux`, `bar.bar.quux`, `bar.corge`. What is the best way to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make a recursive function, that iterates deeply through the properties of the first object, remembers the path of the current property, and investigates if a property with such a path exists in the second object.

There is already a [tool](https://github.com/diedsmiling/keys-diff) written for this case. Just install it:

```
npm install keys-diff
```

And use it like:

```
import keysDiff from 'keys-diff'
const foo = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'baz',
    qux: 'qux'
  }
};

const bar = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'baz',
    quux: 'quux'
  },
  corge: 'corge'
};

keysDiff(foo, bar);
```

The result should be:

```
[ 
  [ 
    [ 'bar', 'qux' ] 
   ], 
   [ 
     [ 'bar', 'quux' ], 
     [ 'corge' ] 
   ] 
]
```